# View iOS Notification Queue?

Tags: ios, push-notification

I was curious if on the iPhone in general (or via iOS simulator) there was some way to see what "push notifications" are queued up?

I googled and find some information on how push notifications are done, but not how they are queued up.

Comment: Push notifications are sent by the back-end, they're not queued on the iPhone. Are you talking about local notifications? If so, `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];` should give you a `NSArray` containing a list of of `UILocalNotification`.

Comment: @AlejandroIván a) pushes from remote are queued as they come in - b) local pushes are queued for delivery and THEN as they come in || not that  it helps the op :D

Comment: @Daij-Djan ah yes, of course, but if the app is opened, it gets delivered immediately (making the queue pointless for that particular app). If the app is closed, and therefore your code not running, you will not be able to catch the notification queue in notification center. So the best shot is to have a notification queue in the back-end. Is there any other way I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This is not possible.

Although, to achieve something like this, you can send a silent push notification to the device to start a content download handler.

This handler can then query your API to get all necessary data and schedule a local notification. See [this programming guide here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW57) for details.

You can also use this mechanism to remove obsolete notifications from the background if, for example, a web-version of the app flagged the information as read.

**EDIT**

The simulator is not capable of handling push notifications at all.

Comment: Hi, just curious. Is it acceptable for approval by Apple to use push notifications to trigger background modes?

Comment: Read the link. It's officially documented. Also, look at apps like Facebook, Facebook Messenger or WhatsApp (Web). If you read a message on the web interface, they remove the notification from the lock screen. Just like iMessages do

Comment: Yes, you could also achieve it with silent notifications (setting badge to `0`). I ask because, for example, if your app downloads files and you send a push notification to start a download, thus triggering a background mode to actually download data, your app could be rejected (or, at least, that's what I understood until now). I was wrong I suppose.